# I want to show result from database without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, laravel

I am working with `laravel`. I have two `div`. One `div` is to show some output from database and other `div` is for showing some output from database.

Let me show my code.

```
<div id="pending">
        @foreach($pendings as $pending)
        {{ $pending->title }}
        <br>
    @endforeach

<div id="accepted">
        @foreach($accepteds as $accepted)
        {{ $accepted->title }}
        <br>
    @endforeach
```

When an user will enter to the page, I want to show him pending `div` or pending data.
Then I want to keep two button. One is PENDING and other one is ACCEPTED. And I want to show pending `div` or pending data when user will click pending button as well as accepted `div` or accepted data when user will click accepted button.
Anyone please help me.

One more think I don't have much knowledge about AJAX or JQuery.

Comment: 1) create endpoints with json 2) display that json after getting it with ajax?

Comment: Look up Javascript AJAX

Comment: If I understood correctly, you want to be able to toggle (i.e switch between two contents)? If this is correct then you may want to consider Bootstrap tabs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#tabs In case I am wrong then let me know...

Comment: @OmisakinOluwatobi, You are absolutely correct. Thank you so much. It was much helpful for me as I don't have enough knowledge JS framework.

Comment: As a side note, you did not close either of your divs in the above example. Not sure if that's creating an issue..

Answer (score 2):

create two buttons with ids button_1 & button_2 and bind db result in single div.You can try below codes

```
function sendAjaxRequest(element,urlToSend) {
             var clickedButton = element;
              $.ajax({type: "POST",
                  url: urlToSend,
                  data: { id: clickedButton.val(), access_token: $("#access_token").val() },
                  success:function(result){
                  /*can add logic for html or json data*/
                   $("#divid").append(result);
                  },
                 error:function(result)
                  {
                  alert('error');
                 }
             });
     }

       $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#button_1").click(function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
              sendAjaxRequest($(this),'/pages/test/');
          });

          $("#button_2").click(function(e){
              e.preventDefault();
              sendAjaxRequest($(this),'/pages/test/');
          });
        });
```

Comment: I am getting this error from console `POST http://localhost:8000/pages/test/ 404 (Not Found) jquery.min.js:4 `

Comment: you have to change the '/pages/test' to the route you are making the request to.

Comment: I have checked by my route. But I am getting this error. `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: Thank you So much for your replay. I have done this with bootstrap.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this with Bootstrap Tabs and Pills.

Comment: it wouldn't be dynamic probably.

Comment: Yes you are right. But I don't have much knowledge in JS framework. Can you Please Suggest me which JS framework should I learn and which part I should learn of that framework to do solve my problem accurately.

Comment: you should practice js and jquery